# What is the equivalent java code in an Android application which has the same effect as pressing a webpage form submit button?

Tags: java, android

I have a microprocessor that hosts a webServer and webpage over wifi and interacts with an Android app. The webpage has a submit button eg HTML

```
<form action="/RUNME" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Run Me">
</form>\
```

When the button is pressed on the opened webpage on the Android device it prompts the server to process its runMe method which executes on a microprocessor.

The microprocessors c code includes this line which when receiving a POST request executes the method runMe

server.on("/RUNME",HTTP_POST,runMe);

I need to achieve the same behaviour from within an android app equivalent to pressing the submit button or
running the runMe routine on the webserver.

The method has to receive the URL eg http://www.xxx.xxx.xx.xx and some argument "/RUNME" or "Run Me". I am unsure of the formatting of the arguments nor which method to use.

```js
String websiteUrl = http://www.xxx.xxx.xx.xx;

 URL url = new URL(websiteUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);//Set output method to POST

        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                                         
        out.write(websiteUrl + "/RUNME");
        out.close();
```

Comment: Post your android attempt

Comment: The `/RUNME` should be part of the URL, not written to the output stream.

Comment: I am uncertain which method to use in HttpURLConnection and how you structure the arguments that include the URL and /RUNME.

Answer (score 0):

Example code block part of my Asynchronous Task

```js
@Override
  protected Integer doInBackground(String[] arg0) {
   
   try {
    url = new URL(arg0[0]);
    urlconn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    urlconn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);    
    urlconn.setDoOutput(true);
    urlconn.setIfModifiedSince(0);
    urlconn.setUseCaches(true);        
    urlconn.setConnectTimeout(3000);
    urlconn.setReadTimeout(3000);
    
    urlconn.connect();
    responseCode =urlconn.getResponseCode();
           
    if(responseCode==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
     
     //POST the HTTP request how to get the same behaviour as pressing the webpage submit buttom
     //How do you do this what method should you use and what arguments that include the url, arg0[0] and /RUNME
     urlconn.????

    }
    
    urlconn.disconnect();
    
           
   } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
            
   return responseCode;
  }
```